# localstorage key undefined in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

This is my service :

```
.factory('$localstorage', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    set: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = value;
    },
    get: function(key, defaultValue) {
      return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
    },
    setObject: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
    },
    getObject: function(key) {
      return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
    }
  }
}]);
```

and I want to store my json into it so I do like below in my controller:

```
$localstorage.set(JSON.stringify($scope.data));
```

I use this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb to check, I found that my value is undefined:
[image]

..my json did passed through, but it goes into the key, not the value. Why?

Comment: Did you check that on the console?

`> window.localStorage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like `set` has a key and a value, and you are just setting the first parameter which is a key?

`$localstorage.set('yourKey', JSON.stringify($scope.data));`